# How create a RACSequence from a method that returns an array

Tags: reactive-cocoa

Given a method that returns an array of objects, how could you create a sequence that is only populated with the results from that method when it is used?

```
- (NSArray *) methodA { ... }

- (RACSequence *) methodB {
  return [self methodA].rac_sequence;
}
```

I am wondering is it possible to avoid execution of methodA unless the sequence is actually used but still return the sequence from methodB to pass on incase I decide to use it.

**Update**

I managed to achieve the behaviour I wanted by using a signal instead of sequence.

```
- (RACSignal *)methodB {
    RACSignal *racSignal = [RACSignal defer:^RACSignal * {
        return [self methodA].rac_sequence.signal;
    }];

    return racSignal;
}
```

Now methodA is only called when the signal is subscribed to.  Why is there no similar concept for deferring sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since you start with an `NSArray`, it's already been evaluated by the time `rac_sequence` is called. If `-methodA` can return a `RACSequence` instead, the evaluation of the sequence would be delayed until it is needed.

Comment: Hi josh, I understand that it is already evaluated.  I don't control the output of methodA but I can control when I call it, I was thinking there might be some way to create a sequence based on a block that executes only the first time it is called.  I am only just starting to look at ReactiveCocoa, so I thought I might have missed something obvious.

Comment: I think I have left it long enough to assume there is no alternative approaches.

Comment: Hi @nacross - what appraoch did you end up using?